# How to Change Colorbar label in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colorbar

```
ax=Dataset_Explore.plot(kind="scatter", x = "Frequency", y="Pulse", alpha=0.8,s=Dataset_Explore["Force_Consolidation"]/1, label="Consolidation Force", figsize=(10,7), c="Power", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"),colorbar=True, sharex=False, title='Title', xlabel="Frequency in Hz", ylabel="Pulse in ms")
```

This is my code and my graph looks like this:

[image: this]

How do I change the label "Power" to "Power in W"?